# Complex cooridinates don't have unique labels?

Tags: complex-analysis

In Tristan Needham's Visual Complex Analysis he asserts that unlike the labeling of real numbers,, coordinates in polar form, on a 2D plane, complex numbers do not have a *unique* label. He goes on to show that by adding multiples of $2\pi$ to an arbitrary complex number's argument, and getting the same complex number.

That's Chapter 1, p.7.

That doesn't make sense to me, because you can do the same thing to numbers in $\mathbb{R}^2$, can you not?

Isn't $$(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2= (r\cos\theta , r\sin\theta)$$
The same as:

$$(r \cos(2\pi+\theta), r \sin(2\pi+\theta)) \text{ ?}$$

---

Verbatim:

> In common with the Cartesian label $ x+iy$, a given polar label $r\angle\theta$ specifies a unique point, but (unlike the Cartesian case) a given point does not have a unique polar label. Since any two angles that differ by a multiple of $2\pi$ correspond to the same direction, a given point as infinitely many different labels:$$... = r\angle(\theta - 4\pi) = r\angle(\theta - 2\pi) = r\angle(\theta) = r\angle(\theta + 2\pi) = r\angle(\theta + 4\pi) = ...$$

Comment: Right. The angle is only unique up to multiples of $2\pi$ [and for the origin, it's totally arbitrary], identical in both, $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{C}$. Unless Needham meant something else, it's a wrong assertion.

Comment: Perhaps Needham is referring to the unique labelling of elements of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: This question seems very unclear without more detail about what Needham says, preferably an exact, word-for-word quotation from the book.

Comment: @WillR I updated the question to include the exact quote.

Comment: Ah, he's saying that the Cartesian representation of a complex number, $x + iy$ with $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$, is unique, while the polar representation isn't.

Comment: @DanielFischer You're right. I can't believe I read that like 20 times and didn't understand it. "Thanks, Brain".